# When tried to click on a element which is disabled, method containing this line of code is exiting

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I tried to click on an element when a popup is opened from application. This element I was trying to click is in the background of the popup. When the code having **.click()** method is executed, the method containing this line of code (line containing **patientSearchPage.patientSearchMenu.click();**) is exiting without any exception and none of the further lines of code is executed[image]

```
public class Recoveries {
public static boolean PatientSearch() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Executing Patient Search recovery");
    boolean success = false;
    PatientSearchPage patientSearchPage = PageFactory.initElements(Generics.driver, PatientSearchPage.class);
    CommonPage commonPage = PageFactory.initElements(Generics.driver, CommonPage.class);

    if(ObjectExist.objectFound(patientSearchPage.patientListGrid) && 
            ObjectExist.objectFound(patientSearchPage.patientSearchMenu))
        success = true;
    else if(ObjectExist.objectFound(commonPage.careMgmtTab)){
        if(CCProGenerics.expandCareMgmtTab()) {
            patientSearchPage = PageFactory.initElements(Generics.driver, PatientSearchPage.class);
            if(ObjectExist.instantExist(patientSearchPage.patientSearchMenu, "After expanding Care Management tab, Patient Search menu")) {
                patientSearchPage.patientSearchMenu.click();
                if(ObjectExist.Exist(patientSearchPage.patientListGrid) && ObjectExist.Exist(patientSearchPage.patientSearchMenu)) {
                    CCProGenerics.waitForDataLoadingStops();
                    success = true;
                }
                else {
                    DriverSheet.addResultToExcel("After click on Patient Search menu, navigation to Patient Search failed");
                    Generics.issues = Generics.issues + "After click on Patient Search menu, navigation to Patient Search failed\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        success = CCProGenerics.login();
        if (success) {
            patientSearchPage = PageFactory.initElements(Generics.driver, PatientSearchPage.class);
            if(ObjectExist.visibleAndExist(patientSearchPage.patientSearchMenu, "After login, Patient Search menu")) {
                patientSearchPage.patientSearchMenu.click();
                if(ObjectExist.Exist(patientSearchPage.patientListGrid) && ObjectExist.Exist(patientSearchPage.patientSearchMenu)) {
                    CCProGenerics.waitForDataLoadingStops();
                    success = true;
                }
                else {
                    DriverSheet.addResultToExcel("After click on Patient Search menu, navigation to Patient Search failed");
                    Generics.issues = Generics.issues + "After click on Patient Search menu, navigation to Patient Search failed\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Please can anyone let me know what is the problem. Need more information, please let me know. This called from @Test annotation

Comment: Post the HTML for the 'Search Combinations' modal. This is why your test is failing -- you cannot click an element in the background while that modal is in the foreground. You need to use the 'x' button to close it first.

Comment: By closing the opened popup I can click and that will definitely work. My doubt is, why I am not getting any exception and this function is exiting

Comment: You have several additional classes and objects referenced in your code snippet, and it appears that all of the Selenium base functionality such as `driver.findElement()` has been wrapped. Those are the pieces of code that will throw exceptions, and that code has not been posted, so until then your guess is as good as mine. `click()` is almost definitely throwing the exception, so maybe you’ve wrapped it in a try / catch somewhere else and the exception is getting swallowed.